# Q: Auto Layout 4 squares Issue/General Auto Layout Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

So I'm just trying to wrap my head around Auto Layout; I understand how to use constraints, just not how to apply them appropriately.  In the picture below I had set no constraints and simply want this simple design to resize correctly on all size classes (Horizontally and Vertically).

http://tinypic.com/r/2ymxbop/9

What constraints would I need to put in to have these squares resize appropriately on all screens (horizontal/vertical) and can you do this in the ( W:Any H:Any ) size class or do you have to set constraints for each individual size class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One size class is all you need in this case.

Set a constraint for each of the 4 gaps between the rects (i.e. the space between the top 2, between the top-left and bottom-left, ...).

Set a constraint for each rect to its 2 closest outer edges.

Now you've set four constraints for each rect - and that's all you need!

Answer (score 0):

For that case: follow the steps

1.Add four uiview to screen, two top and two bottom.
2.In your case the view not touching to bottom layout guide,so you have to give fixed height.

Start the add constraints to views.
All views are correct width and height.
3.So take first view from left top,give leading space ,top space and adjecent spacing to right top view. And select the pin button from the canvas below right side option availabe, select height ,give how much height you need.
4.Now select right top view ,give constraint to top layout guide and trailing space.and also same height what you selected before for view one.
5.Now view three ,left bottom view , give leading ,spacing to top view and right spacing to fourth view and select same height .
6.Now fourth view, give spacing to top view ,trailing to container and select height.
Almost completed.
7.Select all views at once ,give equal withs(option available in pin).

lastly some warning will shows ,do update frames.

Comment: Awesome thank you it worked! Just quick question, why couldn't use just select heights equal on all the squares if they are all the same?  I tried it that way and was curious as to why it didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: ok i understand, but for that xcode then ask bottom constraint ,if you give bottom constraint and equal heights for all views, then  what happens,height of the view increases according to view(still all height same but it bigger height , you cant expect what you want height).